# "sum" being returned as an index of array

Tags: javascript, community, aura, lightning-community

I am seeing a weird issue in a Lightning Community with an Aura Component.

When I loop over this structure:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Contact (OrderApi__Contact__c)",
    "value": "OrderApi__Contact__c"
  },
  {
    "label": "Billing City (OrderApi__Billing_City__c)",
    "value": "OrderApi__Billing_City__c"
  },
  {
    "label": "Billing State (OrderApi__Billing_State__c)",
    "value": "OrderApi__Billing_State__c"
  },
  {
    "label": "Certification (FON_Certification__c)",
    "value": "FON_Certification__c"
  },
  {
    "label": "Activated Date (OrderApi__Activated_Date__c)",
    "value": "OrderApi__Activated_Date__c"
  },
  {
    "label": "Paid Through Date (OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c)",
    "value": "OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c"
  }
]
```

Using `for ... in`, I am getting these keys:

```
for (var index in columnHeadersArray) {
            console.log(index);
        }
0
1
2
3
4
5
sum
```

The `sum` key is throwing an error because when I try to access an Array index, it throws an error. Any reason why I would be getting a `sum` key?

Comment: Only if somewhere in your code there is something equivalent to `columnHeadersArray['sum'] = ...`.

Comment: `columnHeadersArray["sum"]` does return some function, but I dont see that in the Object I am iterating over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use for ... in for this, use an Array.prototype method, such as:

```
columnHeadersArray.forEach((value) => { console.log(value); }) // output elements
```

Or

```
columnHeadersArray.map((value) => value.label); // Makes an array of labels
```

Etc. Check out the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) for the varied methods you can use on an Array or Array-like object.

If the object is actually only *like* an Array, but not a real Array, you can call the method instead:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(columnHeadersArray, (value) => { console.log(value); });
```

See also [this Q&A on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/2132791) about why you should not use for...in to iterate over an Array or Array-like object.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, will do. So you have no idea thought a random `sum` function would be introduced though?

Comment: @BryanAnderson The Q&A I linked hints at this, but to be more precise, for...in loops over all the keys in the object, including any inherited by prototype. In Aura/LWC, most Array methods are overridden to provide Locker Service filtering on data. These methods will then appear in the prototype chain, thus being enumerated in for...in. Presumably, this sum function is a Locker Service variant of the Array.prototype.sum method.

Comment: Oh wow @sfdcfox, thank you very much